# Get local disk drive types using CMD or Java

Tags: java, windows, command-line

In a performance application written in Java I need to know whether the application being run is ran on an SSD, due to it performing a lot of read operations.
I have found ways to find the drive type and whether they are local disks,CD drives or network drives, but not the actual drive type.
Does anyone know of a method that can display me this information? Either from within Java or using a command in the Windows command line?